# I want keep the text in the filer section after a Material-Table rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Im filtering using remote mode in the Material-Table component, but after each filtered, and Material-Table rendered, it delete the text or selection from the filter section.

So I would like to understand if there is a way in the table to keep this values, because it is necessary that the user have reference of what he is seeing in the table.

Im using the last version, 1.32

This is the component https://github.com/mbrn/material-table

Best Regards and thanks in advance for your time in my case

Comment: Does it still happend?

Comment: AS far as i know, Yes, it does. You can override component and insert the data but actually there isnt to much option in filtering in Material-Table

Comment: Can you provide a codepen to reproduce it ?

Comment: Body: props => <MTableBody {...props} onFilterChanged={(columnId, value) => {
                        props.onFilterChanged(columnId, value);

                        // Do you job here 

                      }}/>

Comment: More information about how override a component 
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding

Answer (score -1):

Move your columns object to a state.

Make a state var,
const [materialColumn] = useState([{title: "Name",field: "name"}]);
Then on your material table

```
<MaterialTable
     columns={materialColumnObj}
/>
```

This will solve the problem. The filter text will stay. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, First of all, This is an old question, from version 1.32. (actual version 1.69). 

This library isnot actively maintain anymore. Im not following anymore.

I believe your solution is not complete. 
My advice for better answering is provide codesandbox example. 

Remember=> Your solutions must contain what they call the "remote mode" -> https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/remote-data

Also, override filter component = >More information about how override a component material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding 

Best Regards